# want to keep ajax_loder.gif for one to 2 sceond to display when the user check the username avaliability

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

the problem is the gif  is not shown for desired time  it shows for millisecond and vanish so gif is not able to be seen
where should i put the setTimeout() code or any relevant code to keep the    animated gif  displayed  for 1 to 2 sec. i am not been able to understand that

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name2check"]) && $_POST["name2check"] != ""){
include('connection.php');
$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['name2check']); 
$username = $_POST['name2check']; 
//echo "name $username";
$sql_uname_check = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1"); 
$uname_check =  mysqli_num_rows($sql_uname_check);
if (strlen($username) < 4) {
    echo '4 - 15 characters please';
    exit();
}
if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
    echo "<font color='#FF0000'>First character must be a letter</font>";
    exit();
}
if ($uname_check < 1) {
    echo '<strong>' . $username . '</strong> is '."<font color='#FF0000'   >OK</font><img src='checked.gif' alt='Mountain View'  style='width:50px;height:50px;'>";
    exit();
} else {
    echo '<strong>' . $username . '</strong> is'. "<font color='#FF0000'  >TAKEN</font>";
    exit();
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="ajax_module.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

<script>
function checkusername()
{
var u = _("uname").value;
if(u != "")
{
    _("usernamestatus").innerHTML = '<img src="ajax-loader.gif" width="31"  height="31">';
    //_("usernamestatus").innerHTML = '<img src="checked.gif" alt="Mountain   View" style="width:50px;height:50px;">';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "test.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) 
        {
            _("usernamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.send("name2check="+u);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" oninput="checkusername()"     maxlength="15">
<span id="usernamestatus"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want it to display for 2 seconds, then the following change should work.  The only issue is that if the ajax response itself takes 3 seconds, then the user will now be waiting 5 seconds.

```
if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) 
{
                setTimeout(function () {_("usernamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText}, 2000);
}
```

You could always check to see if 2 seconds has passed before setting the timeout.

```
function checkusername()
{
    var delay = 2000;
    var start = new Date();
    var u = _("uname").value;
    if(u != "")
    {
        _("usernamestatus").innerHTML = '<img src="ajax-loader.gif" width="31"  height="31">';
        //_("usernamestatus").innerHTML = '<img src="checked.gif" alt="Mountain   View" style="width:50px;height:50px;">';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "test.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) 
            {
                var diff = Math.abs(start - new Date());
                if (diff < 2000)
                {   
                    delay = (delay - diff);
                }
                else
                {   
                    delay = 0;
                }
                setTimeout(function () {_("usernamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText}, delay);
            }
        }
        ajax.send("name2check="+u);
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou working as i required :) tried both code liked the first one and thanks once again